# Two groups that are the automorphism groups of each other

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $H,K$ be two non-isomorphic  groups such that $H\cong Aut(K)$ and $K\cong Aut(H)$.

Is there any example of such groups ?

Comment: I'm wondering, and may ask separately, what behaviour is known for taking the Automorphism Group multiple times for finite groups - what are the fixed points (Symmetric Groups other than $S_6$ are included)? Are non-trivial cycles known? Can the groups become unboundedly large, or must every chain end in a fixed point or a cycle? Interesting question, which has got me thinking.

Comment: Can there be a cycle with more than one element?

Comment: related http://mathoverflow.net/questions/151352/iterated-automorphism-groups

Comment: related http://mathoverflow.net/questions/27861/periodic-automorphism-towers

Comment: Wielandt [1939] proved the classical result that the automorphism tower of any centerless finite group terminates in finitely many steps. Rae and Roseblade [1970] proved that the automorphism tower of any centerless Cernikov group terminates in finitely many steps. Hulse [1970] proved that the the automorphism tower of any centerless polycyclic group terminates in countably many steps. Simon Thomas [1985] proved that the automorphism tower of any centerless group eventually terminates. Hamkins proved that every group has a terminating transfinite automorphism tower. Centerless or not.

Comment: I should exclude $S_2$ which clearly has trivial automorphism group from the Symmetric groups which have fixed points.

Comment: The various references are awesome. It looks as though anyone who is able to answer this question one way or the other will have a new result.

Comment: @MarkBennet: If this question has not yet answer, Can you suuply related result or references as answer ?

Comment: I've just read the comments and the MathOverflow links and links on. No-one has given an example.

Comment: one Observation, $H$ is solvable if and only if $K$ is solvable and $H$ is nilpotent if and only if $K$ is nilpotent.

Comment: @NickyHekster: Does your comment means that the answer is no for finite groups ?

Comment: @mesel As far as I can see, Hamkin's results do not imply that there is no nontrivial cycle of automorphism groups of finite groups. He would just consider the direct limit of the whole sequence, and then start again from there. It seems strange that there appears to ne reference to this particular problem in the literature, even as an unsolved problem. It would be worth asking it on MO.

Comment: @DerekHolt: Now, I asked it in MO.

Comment: Here is a [link to the MO question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/193623/two-groups-that-are-the-automorphism-groups-of-each-other).

Answer (score 4):

An answer in the negative for this question would immediately prove the Smith conjecture:
Does the finite part of the automorphism tower of a group G eventually repeat? (Smith 1964)

I have spent some time wrestling with this conjecture, and the pattern I observed was that this did occur and typically very rapidly (only a few steps in, I was using GAP to do the computations, as order of the groups also typically grew rapidly), moreover, every time I found a group for which it began repeating, it was also a reptend of length 1 (meaning the 'last' group was isomorphic to its automorphism group).

If the Smith conjecture is true, and reptend is always length 1, then your question's answer is false, otherwise if the Smith conjecture is true, so is your conjecture, but if Smith's conjecture is false, then it's unclear whether or not you conjecture is true or false.